# Given $AB=0$. Prove that every column of $B$ is a solution for $Ax=0$

Tags: linear-algebra

I am studying for my test by going through some old tests from my university and in one of the tests there's the following question:

> Given $AB=0$ prove that every column of $B$ is a solution for $Ax=0$

And I am very confused, isn't the solution to this problem is obvious? what are they expecting as an answer...?

Isn't it simply:
$AB=0 \rightarrow A[B]^c_i=[0]^c_i$ which shows that every column of $B$ is a solution for $Ax=0$

Answer (score 4):

Here is a formal proof.

Let $e_j$be the column vector with all entries zero, except for the $j$th one, which is $1$.
Then $AB=0$ implies $0=0e_j=(AB)e_i=A(Be_j)=AB_j$, where $B_j$ is the $j$th column of $B$.

The proof relies on the associativity of matrix multiplication.

Answer (score 3):

An alternative approach, using the row-column rule for matrix multiplication:

$$AB = A [ b_1 \quad b_2 \quad \cdots \quad b_n ] = [Ab_1 \quad Ab_2 \cdots \quad Ab_n] = 0, $$

which shows that

$$Ab_j = 0$$

for all $ 1 \leq j \leq n$.